# ArcGIS Visibility <NoData> / 0 when observer point in raster cell center

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.4, 3d-analyst, nodata

As I discovered, the ArcGIS Visibility tool seems to produces a vertical  line from the observer point northwards in the above ground level raster and a 0 value in the visibility Raster, if the observer point is situated directly in the center of a raster cell (in my case derived from it).

Can anyone confirm this, or maybe does someone have a solution?

Moving the point and using a different raster resolution works, but is not what I intended.
I tried using Point and Point z; using SPOT and OFFSETA; setting said z values <, > and equal to the raster value.

I'm using ArcMap 10.4.1

---

edit: cell Values in the example are:

81,510223 | 80,945107 | 81,222015
82,140327 | 81,309288 | 80,910629
81,483345 | 80,921204 | 80,979355

Observer height is derived from the Raster. I also tried using fictious numbers greater and smaller than the raster value.

Interestingly this occurs only for single selected points or for more, if they are in vertical alignment, but not in horizontal alignment.

---

edit2:
After trying to find out, if this would affect my model, I discovered, that by using the extent environment, the fault is averted.
Still, I'm wondering what might cause this.

[image: AGL_NoData]

Comment: I doubt it's the cell *center* which is the issue. Instead, it was the **cell**. Please [edit] the question to report the nine values of the cell and its neighbors, and provide the exact parameters, especially observer height.